# Converting a VBA array into a "column" array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel-2010

As I'm now aware, array in Excel have two kinds of representation :

```
{1,2,3,4} also known as "one-dimensional horizontal array"
```

and

```
{1;2;3;4} also known as "one-dimensional vertical array"
```

I created a VBA function that return an array but when I use it in a function that need arrays (SUMPRODUCT), Excel display it with commas. So it always interpret it as an horizontal array. It's fine if I want to have the product with another horizontal array but it doesn't work when I try with a vertical array.

VBA :

```
Function MyRange()
    Dim output(2)
    output(0) = 1
    output(1) = 1
    output(2) = 1
    MyRange = output
End Function
```

Excel

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MyRange();{1,1,1}) works
=SUMPRODUCT(MyRange();{1;1;1}) is not working
```

My question ?

How I can have Excel to show {1;1;1} instead of {1,1,1} in the 1st array ?

[image]

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(MyRange());{1;1;1})`?

Comment: @ScottCraner If you want to create an answer. I will accept it. Many thanks !

Comment: or maybe `INDEX({1;1;1},0,1)` or `MyRange = Application.Transpose(output)` in VBA

Comment: @Slai Nice catch with TRANSPOSE directly in the VBA. It works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Tranpose to switch it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MyRange();TRANSPOSE({1;1;1}))
```

Comment: Really weird. It looks perfectly in Function Wizard but Excel still return #VALUE! when I click OK !

Comment: I put the TRANSPOSE on the other part `=SUMPRODUCT(MyRange();TRANSPOSE({1;1;1}))` and it's working now ! Many thanks !

Comment: Finally, and unfortunately for me, TRANSPOSE seems to work only on "hardcoded" array. If I use another EXCEL function instead like `TRANSPOSE(--(WEEKDAY(D3:D1257,3)<5))` or `--(TRANSPOSE(WEEKDAY(D3:D1257,3))<5)`, the wizard show it correctly but not in the cell :(

Comment: I follow @Slai suggestion and putting TRANSPOSE directly in the VBA do the trick :)  TRANSPOSE was the right direction. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Another a bit faster option is to use a "vertical" array (not tested):

```
Function MyRange()
    Dim output(1 To 3, 1 To 1)
    output(1, 1) = 1
    output(2, 1) = 2
    output(3, 1) = 3
    MyRange = output
End Function
```

or a bit slower (also not tested):

```
Function MyRange()
    MyRange = [{1;2;1}]
    MyRange(3, 1) = 3
End Function
```